# Finding the period of this periodic function

Tags: trigonometry

How do you calculate the period of the following:

$$x(t)=\dfrac{\sin(2t)+\sin(3t)}{2\sin(t)}$$

Answer (score 3):

As some other answers remarked, the three basic components of $x(t)$, namely $sin(t)$, $sin(2t)$ and $sin(3t)$ have $2\pi$ has *a period*, thus $x(t)$ also has $2\pi$ *a period*.

[Recall that the definition for a function $f(x)$ defined over $\mathbb{R}$ to have $\ell\neq 0$ as *a period* is that for all $x$ we have $f(x+\ell)=f(x)$.

If $\ell$ is a period of $f$, then any multiple of $\ell$ is also a period of $f$. By definition, *the period* is the smallest period of $f$ (if it exists).
]

Now, to show that $2\pi$ is *the period* of $x(t)$, we need to prove that $2\pi$ is not only a period of $x$ but the smallest of those. For this, you need to show that no strict divisor of $2\pi$ is a period of $x(t)$. This can be done, for example, by studying the table of variation of $x$ which shows that the only candidate period would be $\pi$ and then verifying that since $x(0)=5/2$ and $x(\pi)=1/2$, $\pi$ cannot be a period of $x(t)$.

This final step of verifying that no shorter period exists is essential, as shown by the following example:
$$
x'(t)=\frac{sin(3t)+sin(5t)}{sin(t)},
$$
whose period is $\pi$ (and not $2\pi$, despite the fact that $2\pi$ is the lcm of $2\pi$, $2\pi/3$ and $2\pi/5$).

---

**Final remark on the definition of periods:**
The definition given between brackets only applies to function defined all over the real line. If the set of definition of $f$ is a strict subset of $\mathbb{R}$, then we need to add the condition that this set of definition is invariant by translation by $\pm \ell$.

Comment: +1 this is the most complete answer to the OP. @Jason: please feel free to flag and upvote it if you found it useful.

Comment: A great detailed answer! I especially liked the part where you prove that a shorter period doesn't exist! +1 :-)

Answer (score 2):

$$\sin(2t)=2\sin t\cos t$$
$$\sin(3t)=3\sin t-4\sin^3t$$
Thus
$$x(t)=\cos t+\frac{3}{2}-2\sin^2t=2(\cos t+\frac{1}{4})^2-\frac{5}{8}$$
The period of $x(t)$ is $2\pi$

Comment: could you please elaborate how have you derived the period to be $2\pi?$

Comment: OK, let's put it another way. Write $x(t)=\cos (2t)+\cos t-\frac{1}{2}$. Then period is $lcm(\pi,2\pi)=2\pi$. Is it clear now?

Comment: Will the period of $\cos \pi x+\cos 2x?$ be lcm$(2,\pi)=2\pi?$

Comment: Of course not, you have to ensure the ratio of two coefficients is rational

Answer (score 0):

Notice how $x \left( t \right)$ is composed of a combination of $\sin{t}$, $\sin{2t}$ and $\sin{3t}$ terms.  The period of $x \left( t \right)$ is simply the least common multiple (lcm) of each of the sine term's periods.  Therefore the answer is $2 \pi$.

Be careful how you use this 'theorem' however, as it can easily be abused.  For instance, the period of $y \left( t \right) = \left( \sin{2t}+\sin{t}-\sin{t} \right)$ is $\pi$.  If we tried to calculate the lcm without first simplifying $y \left( t \right)$, we might arrive at the erroneous answer $2 \pi$.

Comment: Well, this rule does not always work (even for "simplified" forms). See my answer for a counter example.

Comment: @minar I also listed a counterexample in my answer.  That is why I advised to "be careful" using this rule-of-thumb procedure.

Answer (score 0):

You could start by graphing the function

[image]

But it helps to look at the periods of the separate parts of the function

$\sin(2t)$ has period $\pi$

$\sin(3t)$ has period $\frac{2 \ \pi}{3}$

$\sin(t)$ has period $2 \pi$

We are looking for the shortest period into which each of these divides and the answer is $2 \pi$